# Config Quartz.net with just one thread or make threads Sequentially

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I Have a business in my service that I don't know how long a thread takes time to does its job so I can not set exact interval. Or in another way I want to know how can I set a thread starts after previous one done its job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DisallowConcurrentExecution` attribute on your jobs. The attribute guaranties that the next execution won't start until the current one get completed.

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class MyJob : IJob {
    // whatever your job is
}
```

For making threads sequentially - that I think you mean job get executed as soon as it get completed - you can use one of these scenarios:

1. Set your job `RepeatForEver` and set interval to a very low number e.g. 10 ms
2. Set job's repeatation to once, after it get done, schedule a new (same) job

Both will work.